# Reading parameters from a file consisting one line in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

So I have this shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash -xv

PATH=${PATH[*]}:.
#filename: testScript

echo $#
```

It should print the number of parameters I receive from a text file.
I have a text file(named: file.txt) with one line:

```
I am a proud sentence
```

The output should be, as I understood, 5. Since there are 5 words, there are 5 parameters.
I try to run it by:

```
chmod +x ./testScript.txt

./testScript.txt < ./file.txt > output.txt
```

But I seem to get in output.txt 0, as if there were no parameters. I really barely understand when do I use $1 $2 to approach parameters, and how to actually send parameters into a script.
Should I use pipe? Can it be implented with pipe, anyways?
Also. When a text file is passed to a script. Is $1 the text file's name? Will `echo $1` print `file.txt` for the above example, with only the specified arguments done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`< ./file.txt` sets standard input of the command line to the content of the file.

`read` needs to be used to read standard input.

Maybe this script is closer to your needs

```
#/bin/bash --
printf "%d\n" $#
```

call it with

```
./testScript.txt $(cat ./file.txt) > output.txt
```

`$(...)` makes the shell ececute the command first. The line in the file is then passed as parameters to the script

### ----

Otherwise if you use

```
 ./testScript.txt ./file.txt
```

Then `$1` is equal to `./file.txt`

Comment: Oh, great. For the other question, why is $1 actually the text file's name(file.txt). Where do I make $1 to be it?

Comment: if you use `./testScript.txt ./file.txt` then `$1` is `./file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

```
 ./testScript.txt < ./file.txt > output.txt
```

Here *testScript.txt* has **no** parameters, zero, none, *nothing*.  The shell parses file redirection before the command runs, and `< ./file.txt > output.txt` is just file redirection, so the shell "grabs" that part away -- so *testScript.txt* never knows *which* files are being redirected from standard input and standard output.

This would work, (i.e. output "5"):

```
./testScript.txt I am a proud sentence
```

So would this:

```
xargs ./testScript.txt < file.txt
```

...and so forth (see Jay Jargot's answer).

For more info, this article by Mo Budlong should be helpful: [Command line psychology 101](http://sunsite.uakom.sk/sunworldonline/swol-02-1998/swol-02-unix101.html)

Comment: No, the shell processes and removes redirections before it identifies arguments. Something like `testScript < file.txt arg1 arg2 > output.txt arg3` is valid.

Comment: @chepner, egad, that IS valid!  Interesting, virtually nobody uses it, but still...  Thanks very much for the tip.